# Xcode 12 Module 'RxSwift' was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for '' can't be guaranteed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Once updated to Xcode 12, several warnings showed up:

Module 'RxSwift' was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for 'app' can't be guaranteed

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to remove those warnings.  Those warnings make the Xcode slower when indexing or building.

Comment: Could you create a repository with some minimal project that has this issue? I'm assuming you are using Carthage as that prebuilds dependencies, right?

Comment: No, I am using cocoapods.

Comment: Could be because of ABI compatibility issues. Because you might have updated from an xcode version which had a lower version of a compiler to a xcode with higher version of the compiler. Try deleting all pods via commenting(#) all pods from the project. Clear derived data. Clean Project. Uncomment pods(#). And do pod install again. If all pods are successfully installed, then try doing a Build Again. Theoretically, this should work.

Comment: do you want to fix the problem or ignore these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting these warnings is because the pods are missing the `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` flag in their build settings.

Add the following `post_install` script to your podfile and make sure it's outside your `target 'app' do` block:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
      end
  end
end
```

Check out the following issue for more details:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9232

I wouldn't take this warning lightly. See below discussion on the swift forums:
https://forums.swift.org/t/risks-of-compiler-warning-module-was-not-compiled-with-library-evolution-support/33941